# I'm having trouble restarting openssh server

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface

I'm trying to restart openssh-server in Ubuntu 10.10 by typing:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
sudo: unable to execute /etc/init.d/ssh: Text file busy
```

Comment: What does `ls -l /etc/init.d/ssh` say?  Also, is it sudo itself that's having the problem?  Try running some other command with sudo and see if you get the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it'll make any difference, but Ubuntu's had start and stop service control for a while. E.g:

```
start ssh
stop ssh

start <service-name-here>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have the file /etc/init.d/ssh open for writing somewhere, and therefore can't execute it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384398/usr-bin-perl-bad-interpreter-text-file-busy/1384594#1384594).

What does

```
ps -f -p $(pgrep -f -d, '/etc/init.d/ssh')
```

get you?

Comment: ERROR: List of process IDs must follow -p.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
sudo killall sshd
```

then restart it with

```
sudo service sshd start
```

Comment: hmmm... the killall seemed to work, but the start command says "unrecognized service"

Comment: oh, and even after killall I can still ssh in.  I'm terribly confused.

Comment: When you do a ps -ef|grep ssh what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's also true on Ubuntu but on Debian, you can properly restart your openssh server without using init.d file with:

`# start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd`